# How to have Chef use a different ip?

Tags: chef, vagrant

I'm using a bridged network on a vagrant VM with chef-client.  `knife node show test1-vagrant` shows an ip address of 10.0.2.15, which is eth0.  eth1 is 192.168.1.5, which is what DHCP gave it.  How can i get chef thinking the ip address is 192.168.1.5 instead, so that I can knife ssh -a ipaddress?

Comment: Consider running your VirtualBox VMs in bridged mode instead of NAT mode.

Comment: Even though you have private/public network configured Chef provisioner still uses 10.0.2.15 as node['ipaddress']

Comment: maybe [this is the ticket](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/OHAI-287) on the opscode site?

Answer (score 3):

This cookbook might help you, it changes the `ipaddress` node attribute to use the ip address associated to the `eth1` interface: https://github.com/tknerr/cookbooks-vagrant-ohai

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete Vagrant Plugin that installs an ohai plugin that does something similar
https://github.com/avishai-ish-shalom/vagrant-ohai

Only problem is right now it seems to only install it if you are using the :chef_solo or :chef_server provisioner.